# Adobe Reader XI Settings/Internal Data Location

Tags: adobe-reader

When you open a document from a network location in Adobe Reader XI there is, depending on exact details, a 'Security Warning' dialog that asks you to 'Allow' or 'Block' the file. If you open the file again the dialog is not shown so the file name is stored somewhere but not in the 'Privileged Locations' settings.

Where does Adobe Reader store the list of files that have been 'Allowed'? Alternatively how can I find out what files/settings have changed when I click 'Allow'.

Note that the trusted folders/privileged locations are stored in the registry here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\TrustManager\cTrustedFolders but that this particular dialog does not alter these settings.

To reproduce the exact problem use a Windows 7 PC with Adobe Reader XI. Create a mapped network drive that maps to a shared folder on the same PC with full permission for Everyone (e.g. M:\ maps to c:\AdobeTest). Put on FDF that links to a PDF in the folder and open the FDF with a command line or shell from an application.

Comment: You could use Process Monitor to find which files and Registry entries were accessed. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Is Process Monitor capable of showing if a file is created when the dialog is answered?

Comment: Yes. See a demonstration http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor or http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2010/WCL314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread in the Adobe Forums has a location for saved connections: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3892594?tstart=0#3892594

The key phrase is this: 
Adobe generates a file called DBConnects.sav inside "C:\Documents and Settings.....\Application Data\Adobe\Acrobat\8.0" which remebers the data connection

Answer (score 1):

I can definitively say that it's not stored in the registry. Using RegShot I took a snapshot of the registry before and after a PDF was 'Allowed' and the only relevant change between the two is the recent files list.